# I cannot connect local pgadim to a container that runs postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

i have an issue
i have a container that has a web application running and a postgres db, when i launch the webapp is connected in database correctly, but when in local i tried using a pgadmin that is install on my machine and i try to connect to database of container it gives me an error connection

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3tQb.jpg)

TIPS

- the container has the port-forward of database
- i tried using both localhost and the ip of container as host when initialize connetion using pgAdmin
  I have no idea how to do that, someone can help me

Comment: sorry i edit the question @jjanes

Comment: I notice it translated localhost to ::1 (IPv6).  What happens if you explicitly give the IPv4 address, 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Is the database configured with `listen_addresses='*'`?

Comment: is the same error, but instead ::1 is the ip address 127.0.0.1 @jjanes

Comment: i didn't know that i needed listen_addresses = '*' , thanks @jjanes

Comment: You seem to have attached a link to a JPEG file instead of the error message; can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error?  How are you starting the container and how are you configuring PGAdmin to connect to it?

Comment: i resolve the problem, i missed the line "listen_addresses = '*'" into a configuration file of postgresql, now i can connect with pgAdmin in my machine